# OnItemClickListener stops working when ListActvity called inside layout from another layout file

Tags: android, onclicklistener, listactivity

I could not frame a proper question but here is what I am facing. I have a `ListActvity` and here's the code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class dbMainactivty extends ListActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private ListView noteListView;
    private CursorAdapter noteAdapter;
    private TextView text;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.setScreenName("dbMainactivty");
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

        // Locate ListView
        noteListView = getListView();
        //  setContentView(R.layout.list_note);
        //noteListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        setContentView(R.layout.dbmainactivitylayout);

       text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);


        // Prepare ListView Item Click Listener
        noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewNoteListener);

        // Map all the titles into the ViewTitleNotes TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { TITLE };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ViewTitleNotes };

        // Create a SimpleCursorAdapter
        noteAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(dbMainactivty.this,
                R.layout.list_note, null, from, to);

        // Set the Adapter into SimpleCursorAdapter
        setListAdapter(noteAdapter);


    }


    // Capture ListView item click
    OnItemClickListener viewNoteListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            // Open ViewNote activity
            Intent viewnote = new Intent(dbMainactivty.this, ViewNote.class);

            // Pass the ROW_ID to ViewNote activity
            viewnote.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
            startActivity(viewnote);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Execute GetNotes Asynctask on return to MainActivity
        new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(dbMainactivty.this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();

        // Deactivates the Cursor
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.deactivate();

        noteAdapter.changeCursor(null);
        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(dbMainactivty.this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        //return true;
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //@Override
    //public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //


        //      if (drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        //          return true;
        //      }

        Intent i = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate:
            //          Intent ia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //          ia.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
            //          startActivity(i);
            //break;
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(intent2);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
            Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
            t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("rate CategoryListActivity")  // category i.e. Player Buttons
            .setAction("Button")    // action i.e.  Play
            .setLabel("clicked")    // label i.e.  any meta-data
            .build());


        case R.id.action_share:
            i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "");
            i.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(i);


            Tracker t1 = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
            t1.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("share CategoryListActivity")  // category i.e. Player Buttons
            .setAction("Button")    // action i.e.  Play
            .setLabel("clicked")    // label i.e.  any meta-data
            .build());
            return true;

        case R.id.action_maila:
            Intent imail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            imail.setType("message/rfc822");
            imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
            imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
            imail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(imail, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(dbMainactivty.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

            Tracker t2 = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
            t2.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("Mail CategoryListActivity")  // category i.e. Player Buttons
            .setAction("Button")    // action i.e.  Play
            .setLabel("clicked")    // label i.e.  any meta-data
            .build());
            break;
        case R.id.action_home:
            Intent ihome = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(ihome);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
            Tracker t3 = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
            t3.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("GoToHome CategoryListActivity")  // category i.e. Player Buttons
            .setAction("Button")    // action i.e.  Play
            .setLabel("clicked")    // label i.e.  any meta-data
            .build());
            return true;



        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    };


    // GetNotes AsyncTask
    private class GetNotes extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(dbMainactivty.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // Open the database
            dbConnector.open();

            return dbConnector.ListAllNotes("maincat LIKE 'quiz' AND subcat LIKE 'test'");


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            noteAdapter.changeCursor(result);

            // Close Database
            Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();
            if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                //do your action
                //Fetch your data
                //  GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(dbMainactivty.this).reportActivityStart(this);

                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yipeee!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {


                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No records yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(dbMainactivty.this, "No records yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                finish();
            }  

            dbConnector.close();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(
                    "Please check your Internet Connection.")
                    .setTitle("")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            //loader.cancel(true);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });


            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();

        } else {GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(dbMainactivty.this).reportActivityStart(this);


        }

    }

}
```

Now the layout file for this is `list_note.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.96"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ViewTitleNotes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I implement above code every thing works fine. However, I want to include some other data so i am calling another layout file which includes additional data:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pinned Questions" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
        android:text="There is no data"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I include this layout the list shows up but nothing happens when I click on list item. The normal working would be when I click list item it should open the next activity with desired clicked item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest You To `Implement` `View.OnItemClickListener()` and then use

```
noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

This will work perfectly.
Hope I Helped.